JIRA filter - summary !~ "any 4 digits"
In JIRA, we have a ticket creation policy in which you must provide the unit number in the form of four digits at the beginning of the topic, e.g. 1111, 1234, etc.
Is it possible to create a filter that will show reports where such a number is not included in the topic?
if it was one constant number, e.g. 5555, it would be a simple query:
summary !~ "5555"
but how to make the query search based on summary !~ "any 4 digits"?
Is there any special character in JQL that replaces any digit in queries?

What you are looking for is a regex that matches four digits at the beginning of sentence, something like this for example: ^[0-9]{4}
Sadly, Jira Query Language does not support regex , so the thing you are trying to do is not possible out of the box.
There are, although, apps in the Atlassian Marketplace that will allow you to use Regex in your JQL searches, so maybe you could install one of them to achieve your purpose.

The one that springs to my mind is first is ScriptRunner, because I work at Adaptavist who created it
https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4jc/latest/features/scriptrunner-enhanced-search/jql-functions
